# Unable to resolve path to module '@aws-amplify/ui-react/styles.css'

Tags: css, reactjs, amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

I am getting the error:

> Unable to resolve path to module '@aws-amplify/ui-react/styles.css'

I am using the amplify authenticator component shown in the following link [https://ui.docs.amplify.aws/components/authenticator#quick-start](https://ui.docs.amplify.aws/components/authenticator#customization)

I had already my backend configured as always and is fine and working.

```
npx create-react-app exampleapp
npm start
amplify init
amplify add api
amplify push
npm install aws-amplify @aws-amplify/ui-react
amplify add auth
amplify pus
```

The app.js is configured as follows

```
import { Amplify } from 'aws-amplify';

import { Authenticator } from '@aws-amplify/ui-react';
import '@aws-amplify/ui-react/styles.css';

import awsExports from './aws-exports';
Amplify.configure(awsExports);

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Authenticator>
      {({ signOut, user }) => (
        <main>
          <h1>Hello {user.username}</h1>
          <button onClick={signOut}>Sign out</button>
        </main>
      )}
    </Authenticator>
  );
```

In general the application runs fine and is able to connect with the amplify backend. The problem is that it can not find the css style. It seems that is not in the'@aws-amplify/ui-react'. My Node version is 16.13.1. Also, I am using the last version of the packages at this moment in the package.json

```
"@aws-amplify/ui-react": "^2.1.5",
"aws-amplify": "^4.3.10"
```

Answer (score 5):

When I initially saw @senju's answer (upvote it!) I thought, "that will just hide the problem". But no, in my case eslint was the cause of the problem.

Rather than @senju's solution of disabling warnings for *all* unresolved imports, I suggest just disabling it for the specific import with an eslint-specific comment:

```js
// eslint-disable-next-line import/no-unresolved
import '@aws-amplify/ui-react/styles.css';
```

Comment: What error message where you getting that you needed to add this rule? Is Eslint where the error message is coming from? You can see that `styles.css` is being exported here: https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-ui/blob/main/packages/react/package.json#L27

Can you try upgrading the to the latest version? `npm install @aws-amplify/ui-react@latest`

Comment: @ScottRees I was using the latest version at the time I commented. The error message was the same as OP's. At the time I checked in my node_modules folder and yes indeed the export was there but the error persisted. Sorry I can't test whether it persists now.

Comment: Its weird but only this solution worked for me. Tried everything, also tried issues solutions in their official github, they have mentioned to have fixed in latest versions, still had problem. these problem appears randomly. thanks @cobberboy

Answer (score 2):

Try upgrading `aws-amplify` to 4.3.11 or above and upgrade to the latest version of `@aws-amplify/ui-react`. This version is compatible with the latest version of create-react-app which uses Webpack 5. This issue was fixed in `aws-amplify` here:
https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/pull/9358

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I have the same problem with aws-amplify v4.3.13

Comment: @SimonOrro What version of `@aws-amplify/ui-react` are you on? Can you try upgrading to the latest?

Comment: I'm running into the same issue just trying to get an official AWS Workshop running https://catalog.us-east-1.prod.workshops.aws/workshops/bb080ee8-4722-4290-ac6e-d4cde0a65142/en-US/02-setup-web-application/02-add-authentication

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. Changing my `eslint` setting worked for me.

Here is my `.eslintrc`

```
{
  "extends": [
    "next",
    "next/core-web-vitals",
    "prettier",
    "plugin:testing-library/react",
    "plugin:import/recommended",
    "plugin:import/warnings",
    "plugin:storybook/recommended"
  ],
  "rules": {
    "import/no-unresolved": "off", //add
    "import/order": [
      "error",
      {
        "alphabetize": {
          "order": "asc"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "overrides": [
    {
      "files": ["*.stories.@(ts|tsx|js|jsx|mjs|cjs)"],
      "rules": {
        "storybook/hierarchy-separator": "error",
        "storybook/default-exports": "off"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the latest version of aws-amplify and still got the error on build. Changing .eslintrc worked.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).